# cambio de valores de nodos de una linked list en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodos, javascript-metodo

Tengo que cambiar el valor de 2 nodos en una linked lista de javascript, todos los test pasan excepto uno, si pongo como pos2 un valor superior a la cantidad de nodos que tiene la lista, hace el cambio con el ultimo nodo y me devuelve true, y lo que debería hacer es sólo devolverme false... Creo que es como hice el planteo pero no puedo ver mi error... Alguien me da una mano.. gracias!!

'''

```
  LinkedList.prototype.switchPos = function (pos1, pos2) {
  if (pos1 < 0 || pos2 < 0) return false;
  if (pos1 == pos2) return true;
  if (pos1 == undefined || pos2 == undefined) return false
  let num1 = 0;
  let num2 = 0;
  let current1 = this.head;
  let current2 = this.head;
 
  while (pos1 != num1 && current1.next !== null) {
    num1++;
    current1 = current1.next;
  }
  
  while (current2.next !== null && pos2!==num2){
    num2++;                                       
    current2 = current2.next;
  }
  
  let value1 = current1.value;
  current1.value = current2.value;
  current2.value = value1;
  console.log(current1.value)
  console.log(current2.value)
  return true;
};
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

```
let counter = 1;
let current = this.head;
while (current.next !== null) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    current = current.next;
}
if (pos1 > counter || pos2 > counter) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu respuesta para describir el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.